# Securing Web Application in Java using SSL and digital signature

Tags: java, spring, rest, security

I am new to programming world, so can any one help me how can i apply SSL and digital signature in a web application . How to create a dummy SSL certificates and digital signature. 
I know how to apply http basic/digest/form security on spring or servlet application but i don't know how to work with SSL,Digital sinature and how to configure url as https.

Comment: You can get a cert for cheap for testing, but look up "self-signed certificate" for the freebie version.

Answer (score 0):

You can create test SSL certificates and keys with openssl.

[How to create a self-signed certificate with openssl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10175812/how-to-create-a-self-signed-certificate-with-openssl)

Also you can generate CA certificate and ssl certificates with XCA tool which has user interface support. It uses openssl for generating certificate and keys.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/xca
https://campus.barracuda.com/product/campus/doc/28475773/how-to-create-certificates-with-xca/